# How to create multi level index from multiindex column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

The main goal is to set multi-index row from existing `df`.

Say we have multilevel column as below

```
        level1            
        level2            
      sub_name   A   B   C
ONE         TT  11  12  13
TWO         TT  21  22  23
THREE       TT  31  32  33
```

then, the intended output (1)

```
           level1        
           level2        
           A   B   C
TT ONE       11  12  13
   TWO       21  22  23
   THREE     31  32  33
```

I have the impression this can be achieved by `group` OR directly using `set_index`, as below

```
df = df.groupby((slice ( None ), slice ( None ),'sub_name'),as_index = False)
```

OR

```
df=df.set_index([(slice ( None ), slice ( None ),'sub_name')])
```

However, this is not working.

Such that the first approach return an error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

and second approach

> TypeError: The parameter "keys" may be a column key, one-dimensional
> array, or a list containing only valid column keys and one-dimensional
> arrays.. Received column of type <class 'tuple'>

May I know what is the proper way of achieving the intended goal.

The full code to reproduce the above error

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ( {'A': [11, 21, 31],
                     'B': [12, 22, 32],
                     'C': [13, 23, 33]},
                    index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'] )

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product ( [['level1'], ['level2'], df.columns] )

df2 = pd.DataFrame ( ['TT'] * len ( df ), index=df.index,
                     columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product ( [df.columns.levels [0],
                                                           df.columns.levels [1],
                                                           ['sub_name']] ) ) 
# Im just curios whether there is simpler way of creating constant column like this


df = pd.concat ( [df2,df ], axis=1 )

# df = df.groupby((slice ( None ), slice ( None ),'sub_name'),as_index = False)

# df=df.set_index([(slice ( None ), slice ( None ),'sub_name')])
```

With support from [contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14289892/anurag-dabas).

The bonus question was whether it is possible to add another level on top of `TT` without the need of creating constant column (i.e.,`df2`)

```
               level1
               level2
               A   B   C
main_level TT  ONE     11  12  13
               TWO     21  22  23
               THREE   31  32  33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `set_index()`+`xs()`+`swaplevel()`+`drop()`:

```
df=(df.set_index(df.xs('sub_name',axis=1,level=2).values.squeeze(),append=True)
      .swaplevel(0).drop('sub_name',axis=1,level=2))
```

output:

```
            level1
            level2
            A   B   C
TT  ONE     11  12  13
    TWO     21  22  23
    THREE   31  32  33
```

**Note:** you can also use `df.loc[:,(slice(None),slice(None),'sub_name')]` in place of `df.xs('sub_name',axis=1,level=2)`

**Update:**

you can try `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`:

```
df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['main_level'],['TT'],df.index.unique()])
```

output:

```
                        level1
                        level2
                        A   B   C
main_level TT   ONE     11  12  13
                TWO     21  22  23
                THREE   31  32  33
```

Comment: Thanks @Anurag. btw Im just curios whether it is possible to create another level ('main_level) on top of `TT` without creating the `constant column`(i.e., df2). For example, the expected output will be something:             level1
            level2
            A   B   C
main_level TT  ONE     11  12  13
    TWO     21  22  23
    THREE   31  32  33

Comment: Sorry, the comment is not well formatted.But im not sure whether this curiosity worth new post or not.

Comment: @balandongiv you can add that in question

Comment: @balandongiv so you don't want any value in main_level?

Comment: `TT` will be subset `main_level`

Comment: Thanks for the effort and sorry for making the question not clear. But, what I expected is , if I can represent it in different form: main_level TT  ONE ,main_level TT  TWO ,main_level TT  THREE.

Comment: Thanks, the new update solve the main and bonus question as below:`df=df.set_index([['TT']*len(df)],append=True).swaplevel(0)` and
`df=df.set_index([['main_level']*len(df)],append=True).swaplevel(0)`. Importantly, we can now skip creating a constant column.+1

Comment: @balandongiv updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: btw, can you keep the `df=df.set_index([['TT']*len(df)],append=True).swaplevel(0)` for my future reference. Thanks

Comment: @balandongiv pls feel free to edit this answer according to your need **:)**

Comment: Rename index column: df=df.rename_axis ( index=['main_level', None] ) # edit the naming

Comment: @balandongiv you don't need to run `set_index()` 2 times..updated answer ..kindly have a look **:)**